# Un-signing/Decoding JWTs from internal API

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I'm modifying our laravel site to authenticate users through our own internal API rather than just against passwords in the database.

When the API is called, and the user is verified as existing, it returns multiple JWTs with their own scopes. I need to un-sign, decode and cache those.

My issue is that I've looked into packages for laravel to do this with JWTs and even installed the Tymon library to look into it, but that seems to be more about issuing the tokens through Laravel.

I have this login function that, once the user signs in, dumps the encoded tokens on the login page view:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $authService = new AuthService();
    $login = $authService->loginGetToken($email, $password);
    dd($login);
    //var_dump($login); //this dumps upon 'sign in' then redirectes to login page

    return redirect(route('auth.login'))
        ->with('login', $login);
}
```

So I've successfully returned my multiple JWTs from the API, but what is the best way to go about un-signing and decoding them here? I have a public key to use for the keys but I'm not sure how I can successfully dump unsigned and/or decoded tokens into the view so that I can see the scopes on my page for debugging.

Comment: What's the module or whatever you are using? Typical JWT lib is gonna provide decode/encode methods. eg. https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

Comment: I think that makes sense. So ```$login``` is a call to my REST function that sends the email and password to our API, which sends back the tokens. DUmping $login shows the 4 encoded tokens, so if I use that library I should just be able to wrap that in the decode function?

Comment: Would think so. Try it and see. Might need to verify algorithm used on encoding. Probably work with defaults, likely HMAC-SHA256. Might all sound fancy but there isn't much to this. Suggest reading wiki page on JWT and maybe taking a peek at the source code for that library I referenced just to demystify things. I think you've got this.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it working from it's end. However, I'm getting an error due to having multiple tokens (it's expecting one token with correct # of segments). I'm going to keep trying by declaring each token though